# issue in writing to a file in application sandbox IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am trying to load a webpage in a `uiwebview`.
now this page rander the content based on a `json` file.

also this file is populated by ext rating a web services.
what i am doing is i am populating this json file using web services and rendering this content on the page displayed on `web view`.

but the issue is it is working fine when i am executing it on simulator.
but its not working on my device.

here is the code. 
i will highlight the concerned line.

```
 NSURL *jsonURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://r099:8080/WebServiceforiPad/rest/ipad/content/login/"];
   // NSLog(@"%@",jsonSourcePathName);
    NSString *jsonfileString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@",jsonfileString);



    NSString *documentDirectory=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *jsonFilePath=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"b2b_capability_eris.json"];
    NSLog(@"###########%@",documentDirectory);

    [jsonfileString writeToFile:jsonFilePath atomically:YES encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
```

Comment: I think you dont have .json file in your documents directory

Comment: May be the URL is not global. means it is localsystem i think.

Comment: @Tendulkar correct my file is not in document directory...
but if i put it in document directory it would not be accessed by my web page then...

Comment: Please further explain "not working on my device".

Comment: @MarcusAdams i mean if i m running it on mac.... it takes the url and works fine .... but things are different for apple devices.... the "sandbox thing"

Comment: @MayurGupta Does the sandbox not work on the iPhone Simulator then?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes it is working for iphone simulator....

Comment: @MayurGupta No; I mean "Is the App sandbox implemented in the iPhone Simulator?".  You seem to think not, but I don't see why that would be.

Comment: Maybe it's a network issue. You're making a synchronous call to your web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `r099` is your actual host name, then ensure that the device is able resolve that to an IP address and that the address is reachable from the device's network connection.

The simulator is able to use your Mac's network (including `/etc/hosts` file), while your device is stuck with your wireless (cellular or wi-fi) network. If the DNS server(s) for your device's connection can't resolve the host name, you're out of luck.

You can try using an IP address rather than a host name if your web server has a single web host (this often won't work on shared web hosts).

If your device's connection is using your ISP's or data service provider's DNS servers, it's not likely going to be able to resolve anything on your local network. Your device would need a host name that resolves and is reachable on the Internet.

If your device is using your wi-fi connection and is using a DNS server on your local network, then you need to ensure that the DNS entry has been added for that host name. Again, if your wi-fi settings are using your ISP or data provider's DNS server, then see above.